# VCenter Maintenance mode REST API is not working

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter, maintenance-mode

I am trying to use the REST API /api/vcenter/host/maintenance/requests-v1 to move the ESX host to Maintenance mode. POST action was success. But host does not move to maintenance mode.

I have a vSphere v8.0 Trial version deployment where I am experimenting the Maintenance mode REST API.
I have two ESX hosts and no cluster, no DRS, no HA in the setup.

I was able to move a host to maintenance mode from vSphere client web UI.

The host does not have any VMs running. Ready to be moved to maintenance mode.

I tried to use the REST API /api/vcenter/host/maintenance/requests-v1 from POSTMAN and the POST action was success and I am seeing the requests in the GET call to the above API.

But the host is not setting to maintenance mode in V-Sphere web client.

Am I missing any configurations/settings?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around with pyvmomi library. Using host.EnterMaintenanceMode(TIMEOUT) API.

You need to have pyvmomi, requests libraries installed in your .venv.
I disabled SSL verification for my testing.

Posted a sample code to test this.

```py
import requests
import pyVim    
from pyVim import connect, task
import ssl

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
TIMEOUT =30
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

my_cluster = connect.SmartConnect(host="{{vcenter_ip}}", port=443, user="{{user}}", pwd="{{pwd}}", sslContext=context)
searcher = my_cluster.content.searchIndex
host = searcher.FindByIp(ip="{{host-ip}}", vmSearch=False)
task1 = host.EnterMaintenanceMode(TIMEOUT)
task.WaitForTask(task1)
print (host.name)
connect.Disconnect(my_cluster)
```